# Add an event directly to the Calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to add an event directly with this code:

```
// Construct event details
long startMillis = 0;
long endMillis = 0;
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2013, 3, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2013, 3, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();


// Insert Event
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Walk The Dog");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "My dog is bored, so we're going on a really long walk!");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
values.put("eventTimezone", "Europe/London");
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
// Retrieve ID for new event
String eventID = uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

This code syntactically is correct, but does not add event to the Calendar.
What is the problem?
And Eclipse says that

```
String eventID = uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the `WRITE_CALENDAR` permission to be able to create event this way.

Also, in your sample, the `eventID` variable is indeed not used -> you do nothing with it.

Comment: Sorry, I had already
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

Comment: I forgot to say that I also have an error:
error opening trace file: no such file or directory (2)